# How to pass depth buffer from OGRE to CUDA?

Tags: opengl, ogre, depth-buffer, cuda

I am using OGRE for rendering some objects. At every frame, I would like to pass the resulting depth buffer to CUDA for running some kernels on it and computing a result.

How can I achieve this? How do I get access to depth buffer in OGRE? How do I pass this to CUDA for processing? I do not need to write to the depth buffer in the CUDA kernels, it can be read-only.

Comment: This question has been answered on SO, however only for Direct3D: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140255/how-to-pass-depth-buffer-from-ogre-to-cuda

Answer (score 1):

Firstly to get CUDA working you will need to download the correct drivers from NVIDIA for your graphics card.

You will also need to download the [CUDA SDK](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) and link against it and #include it in your program.

you can send data to the GPU by allocating a buffer and copying it to the GPU as so:

```
char *buffer;
cudaMalloc( (void**)&buffer, yourBufferSize );
cudaMemcpy( buffer, yourDepthBuffer, csize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
```

To execute a kernel on this data

```
dim3 dimBlock( 1, 1 );
dim3 dimGrid( 1, 1 );
testKernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(buffer);
//You'll probably want to decide on your own block size etc ...
```

Where the test Kernel is

```
__global__
void testKernel(char *a)
{
    a[threadIdx.x] = .....; //whatever you want to do
}
```

To get the result back you use

```
cudaMemcpy( yourResult, buffer, yourBufferSize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );
```

And of course clean up after yourself

```
cudaFree( buffer);
```

That's the overall gist of it anyway. You'll probably need to fill is some gaps like error handling and so forth, but I figured it best to keep it simple.

See [here](http://www.nvidia.com/content/GTC-2010/pdfs/2131_GTC2010.pdf) for a walkthrough of the basics.